# for and if in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have checkbox filled with a database and I structure as a result.

```
<div class="all_checkbox">
 <div> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" style="float:left;"name="option_<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">  
  </div> 
  <div style="margin-left:24px;"> 
     <label for="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" >
              <?php echo $data['cat_title']; ?>
     </label> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

and I want to test the checked checkbox –
I have the following code in java script :

```
function add_cat(){
  for (i=1; i<55; i++)
  {
    if(document.getElementById(i).checked == true )
    { 
      alert(i);
    }   
  }
}
```

The `for` loop doesn't reach 55. It stops at 6. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Nothing logged in the console of your browser? (I mean: are you sure you have an element with ID "6" (and "7"...)?

Comment: Please use a translation service to provide the question in English.  If the English is sloppy its ok.  Your code sample appears incomplete like it is missing the opening part of a function or includes an extra curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question as I don't speak French, but...

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**EDIT**

Ah it's been translated now (thanks whoever did that). I still think this is your problem though.

Comment: The for loop doesn't reach 55. It stops at 6. so it work for the 6 first element , :(

Comment: The loop is fine. Remove the if statement and it loops the correct number of times. The problem is you're looking for elements with an invalid ID (starts with / is a number).

Comment: Now either that's your problem, or they're just not checked. The loop itself is sound. Maybe post some HTML so we can get a better idea what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ID naming rules at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp
It must begin with a letter and can be followed by letters,digits,hiphens,underscore,colon,period.
Also check if all ID's are present in your document before runningn the loop. If any ID in the specified range is not present then you get an error like this:
`TypeError: document.getElementById(i) is null` 
and execution will stop at that point. 
I think  that is  the reason in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop will execute its body for `i=1` until `i=54`, then `i` will be incremented to 55 and it will stop.

However, it is likely that some code in your loop body throws an exception, causing the loop (and the whole script) to stop. This is probably a `object is null - can't access property` type error, thrown when your `document.getElementById(i)` does not find any element. Check your error console. To avoid that, you might change your code to

```
 var el = document.getElementById(i);
 if ( el && el.checked ) …
 // which is short for
 if ( el != null  && el.checked == true ) …
```

Btw, numbers are no valid html identifiers. This won't break your code, but you still should address that issue.

Comment: thinks :) but i don't found where :(

Comment: Use your browser's javascript debugger to find the exact line

Answer (score 0):

This FOR loop does loop with i values from 1 to 54.

Comment: no it's interruptin element 6

Comment: @Killer Whale have you verified this in firebug? use ID's starting with a letter!